# Archive data after every year

Tags: django

I have lots of models in my project like Advertisements, UserDetails etc. Currently I have to delete the entire database every year so as to not create any conflicts between this year data and previous year data. 
I want to implement a feature that can allow me to switch between different years. What can be the best way to implement this?

Comment: If you want to make Python based solution then try [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/). You can create a task that will be running in every year. Although if you use some kind of database like PostgreSQL then you can use something like [pg_cron](https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2016/09/09/pgcron-run-periodic-jobs-in-postgres/) or other equivalent depending on your database stack.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @Deepstop I am using PostgreSQL

Comment: @xbound I actually don't  want to delete any data or run any periodic jobs. I want a feature to archive the data of certain number of models so that  if I want I can switch to that archive anytime.

Comment: You might be able to use a custom manager in some way:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/managers/#modifying-a-manager-s-initial-queryset.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could switch schemas in PostgreSQL. It's not completely straightforward. There are several ways to do that you can look into. The way I did it was to use a default search path for the Django database user account (e.g. user2018, user2019, etc) that only included the schema I wanted to use. I can't check the exact settings right now because my office network is down. You can also do it in settings.py or in each individual model using db_table according to what I've read, although both those solutions seem more convoluted that using the search path.

You would have to shutdown, change the database username in `settings.py` (or change the search path in PostgreSQL,  change the schema over to a new one, and then run `migrate` to create the tables again. If you have reference data in any of the tables then schema-to-schema copies are easy to do.

Try searching for `change django database schema postgresql` to see what options there are for specifying the schema.